# Ajax fires up multiple times unless page is Reloaded, Rails 4 and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple app with **index** and **show** pages. Pretty simple code and etc.
Simple registration that is handled with Devise gem.

In index page I have such **Bootstrap modal for registration:**

```
     <div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog log-modal">
                            <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="user-registration-content">

                            <div class="modal-header clearfix">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title pull-left"><%= t('user_creation') %> <!--Lietotāja izveide --></h4>

                                <%= link_to '#',:class=>"pull-right",:id=>"login-path-link" do %>

                                               <span><%= t('already_registered') %> <!--Jau esi reģistrēts --></span>
                                    <%end%>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <span><%= t('please_fill_form') %></span>

                                <%= form_for(@user, :html => {:id=>"sign_up_user" ,:class=>"registration-form-modalc","data-parsley-validate" => true},remote: true, format: :json,as: @user, url: registration_path(@user)) do |f| %>

                                    <div class="form-group">                                    
                                         <%= f.text_field :name,:class=> "user-input form-control", :id=>"user-name",autofocus: true ,:placeholder=> t('username_2'),:required => true,:'data-parsley-minlength'=>"3"%>                                    
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">                         
                                         <%= f.password_field :password,:id=>"passwordis",:class=> "user-input form-control", autocomplete: "off" ,:placeholder=> t('new_password'),:required => true,:'data-parsley-minlength'=>"8" %>                                     
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :id=>"password-again",:class=> "user-input form-control", autocomplete: "off" ,:'data-parsley-equalto'=>"input#passwordis",:placeholder=> t('new_password_2'),:required => true,:'data-parsley-minlength'=>"8"%>
                                        <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => "user"%>
                                        <%= f.hidden_field :country_id, :value => @location.id%>                                                        
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <%= f.email_field :email ,:class=>"user-input form-control" ,:'data-validatess' => '/blocked/checkemail',:id=>"emailito",:placeholder=> t('email'),:required => true%> 
                                         <h3 id="email-taken-message" style="display:none;margin-left:140px;color:red;padding-top:7px;"> <%= t('email_not_available') %> </h3>                                                                                                                
                                    </div>

                                    <%= f.hidden_field :humanizer_question_id %> 



                      <div class="question-content" style="position:relative;top:1px;">

                              <span class="question"><%= t('question') %>:</span>

                              <span class="answer"  >
                                 <%= f.label :humanizer_answer, @user.humanizer_question %>  
                              </span>

                              <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:21px;">
                               <span class="question" style="margin-top:8px;"><%= t('answer') %>: *</span>                              
                                   <%= f.text_field :humanizer_answer ,:class=> "form-control",:required => true, :id=>"answer"%>
                              </div>                                            
                       </div>

                        <%= f.submit t('confirm'),:class=> "blue-button btn btn-default"%>

                                <div class="squared">

                                    <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service,:id=>"accept",:required => true,:type=> "input"%>
                                    <!--<input type="checkbox" value="" id="accept" name="check" /> -->
                                    <label style="left: 0px;"for="accept"><span><%= t('read_and_agree') %> <!--Izlasīju un piekrītu  -->


                                    <%= link_to t('rules_2'),help_path, :target=>'_blank' %>
                                    </span>

                                    </label>


                                </div>

                                <div class="squared">

                                    <%= f.check_box :not_a_robot,:id=>"user-status",:required => true, :type=> "input"%>
                                    <label style="left: 0px;"for="user-status"><span><%= t('not_robot_confirm') %></span></label>

                                </div>


                                <div class="squared">
                                 <%= f.check_box :im_old,:id=>"user-age",:required => true, :type=> "input"%>

                                    <label style="left: 0px;"for="user-age"><span><%= t('already_adult') %></span>

                                    </label> 
                                </div>

                            </div>

<%end%>

</div>

               </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

At the end of the **Application_layout** file:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>  

    <script src="/assets/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "co.js" %>

    <script src="/assets/scripts.js"></script>
```

Registration process is handled with **remote => true.**

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("form#sign_up_user").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {


             $(".user-registration-content").hide();
             $(".registration-sent").show();


  }).on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {


    alert("Error user registration");

  });
});
```

**Application.js file:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require turbolinks
//= require parsley
//= require_tree.
```

**Problem**: Unless I refresh page before triggering modal and filling in form, submitting form triggers 2 identical requests. If I visit show page and then come back to index page to register form submitting triggers 4 identical requests.

Basically, each time user visits show page number of requests increases by 2. At the end requests can go up to 10 and more. After reloading page everything is back to normal.

The same problem occurs when I click on page logo that sends to root_path that is basically the same index page. And the cycle continues.

**What I tried:**

1) Deleted every other script from scripts.js file except the script for handling registration process (see above for script)

2) Changed all click elements to `.one('click', function(`)

3) Removed every other Bootstrap modal from my page so the conflict possibility could be excluded.

4) Double checked page source for **index** and **show** page to check if `script.js` file is called just once.

5) I have cleared tmp/assets folder.

6) Problem happens on all browsers.

**Note**: This problem occurs on every ajax request. In my app I have lot of modals with ajax submitting and every of them have the same problem unless I reload page each time.

I have run out of options to try.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried with .off() prior .on()? Example: $("form#sign_up_user").off("ajax:success).on("ajax:success") ... http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: @salih0vicX   Yes, I just tried. Still multiple ajax requests happen. I think problem is somewhere else, because my bootstrap modal background color is fully black after few show page visits. But when I reload page, modal background is back to normal - light gray.

Comment: @salih0vicX   .  I fixed my problem. It was caused by Turbolinks gem. I removed it from application.js and Gemfile. Then bundle install.